# Render twig component in a loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig

objective : **products database + twig component rendered in a loop.**

I have this setup:

- A .twig product component with my component markup:

```
<article class="productCard "><h3 class="productCard__name">{{ product.name }}</h3></article>
```

- A loop in my page which I want to display all the instances of the product but with the twig component template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="col">
        {{ include('components/productCard.html.twig'),{'product.name': product.name}) }}
    </div>
    {% if loop.index % 4 == 0 %}
        </div><div class="row" >
    {% endif %}
```

- A Database with the actual list of product.

I'm not sure of the correct syntax of the loop call to achieve what I want (passing the parameters of the database to the loop to the component).

Comment: What you're looking for is basically how to send an array of products to the template as a variable?

Comment: I think so.. how can i say it.. i want my products rendered in my page each with this template and their own variables ?

Comment: Ah, I see now after the edit that you already have a loop... you have an extra closing parenthesis there: `productCard.html.twig'),` - you're closing the `include` call here.

Comment: I think that passing the whole product variable will work better: `{{ include('components/productCard.html.twig', { product: product }) }}`

Comment: ^ you don't have to explicitly send the variable `product` to the template as it will be known anyway inside the included template due to the loop

Comment: Thanks everyone so If I understand well, I can use {{ include('components/productCard.html.twig', { product: product }) }} or simply {{ include('components/productCard.html.twig') }} and <h3 class="productCard__name">{{ product.name }}</h3> in my template ?

Comment: you don't need to pass product object in include. just pass the list of the products from the controller. twig is not like react or vuejs ;)

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax would be:

```
{% include 'components/productCard.html.twig' %}
```

No need for using `with` or passing variables.  Then your other snippet should work as-is:

```
<article class="productCard">
    <h3 class="productCard__name">{{ product.name }}</h3>
</article>
```